# How to download ovpn file from openvpn-as via cURL

Tags: bash, curl, openvpn

I am trying to authenticate to my openvpn-as server via curl command. My end goal is to be able to download the ovpn file as I would via the browser but via the cli. I was able to get the cURL command from the browser but I get a 403.

My curl command looks like this:

```
curl -iL 'https://192.168.35.229:943/?src=connect' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01' \
  -H 'X-OpenVPN: 1' \
  -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
  -H 'X-CWS-Proto-Ver: 2' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36 OPR/70.0.3728.178' \
  -H 'Origin: https://192.168.35.229:943' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  --data-raw 'username=dummy&password=dummy' \
  --compressed \
  --insecure
```

The response looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Set-Cookie: openvpn_sess_c6bec1b42f39a6d1034a54580d5422dc=36bce77626a6e403eb6ae9f02576d460; Expires=Wed, 16 Sep 2020 05:15:12 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Server: OpenVPN-AS
Location: https://192.168.35.229:943/__session_start__/
Date: Wed, 16 Sep 2020 04:45:12 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 16 Sep 2020 04:45:12 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: OpenVPN-AS

<html><head><title>Forbidden</title></head><body><h1>Forbidden</h1>Request was forbidden.</body></html>#
```

I wasn't able to find any examples or instructions about this in the documentation. Is there a way to achieve this via CLI - via bash script ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution based on [this article](https://openvpn.net/images/pdf/REST_API.pdf) . The curl command would look like:

`curl -u dummy:dummy -k https://192.168.35.229:943/rest/GetUserlogin`